# fetching data from multiple tables with multiple foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql

The main table is `CAR` table that looks like this:
[image]

The next table is a `MODEL` table that looks like

[image]

The other table that I'm dealing with is called `BODY_TYPE` and it looks like this

[image]

The last table that I'm dealing with is called `MAKE` and it looks as illustrated in the following image

[image]

Now what I'm looking to achieve is to fetch `MODEL` that matches `BODY_TYPE` and the `MAKE` and must be available on the `CAR` table.

Basically, `CAR` contains all cars, so the data that I'm supposed to fetch must be in `CAR`. If a model is not available on the car table then it should not be shown.

this is my code but it keeps returning empty results. Not sure where am going wrong. I have tried for hours with no success

```
function fetch_model_options( $boody_type, $make ){
    $conbd = Conectar_two();

    $Query = "select mo.model from CAR c, MODEL mo, MAKE m , BODY_TYPE bo
            WHERE mo.id_model = c.id_model and 
            c.id_make = m.id_make AND 
            (
                ( mo.id_body_type = bo.id_body_type AND bo.body_type LIKE '%$boody_type%' AND c.id_body_type = bo.id_body_type  )
                AND
                ( mo.id_make = m.id_make AND m.make LIKE '%$make%' )
            )
            AND
            c.available =1 
            group by m.id_make";

    
    if ($Result = $conbd->query($Query)){
        echo "There are some results\n";

        while($reg = $Result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){

            
        echo '<option value="'.$reg['model']. '">'.$reg['model']. '</option>' . "\n";                                       
        //printf("<select class='form-control'>" ,$reg["body_type"]);   
        //$tmp = "<select class='form-control' id='".$reg["body_type"]."'>";
        
        //echo("<option value='' id='".$reg["body_type"]."'>");
        //echo $tmp;
        //printf($reg["body_type"]); 
        
        }
        $Result->free();
    } else {
        echo "no results\n";

    }

//$conbd->free();
//<option value="">All</option>

}
```

Comment: Please learn to use ANSI JOIN in your queries, not cross products. They're much easier to read and write.

Comment: You're missing `AND` before `c.available =1`

Comment: You need to add error checking, then you would have know about the syntax error.

Comment: I have added the missing AND and edited the question. My question is however not in anyway related to the pointed duplicate questioni

Comment: You have `<option>` elements without `<select>`. What are you expecting to see?

Comment: Which message are you getting, "there are some results" or "no results"?

Comment: for now i"m using console I'm expecting to see the right results. forget about the HTML used to render data. Essentially think of it like just a normal echo without HTML for that matter

Comment: If the PHP is not relevant, you should leave it out of the question so it doesn't confuse the issue. Can you make a fiddle with sample data? We can't cut and paste your screen shots.

Comment: Why are you using `GROUP BY m.id_make` without any aggregation functions?

Comment: FYI, your "no results" message is printed when there's an error in the query, not when the query is valid but doesn't find any matches.